# How to install Windows 8 with BootCamp 5 Assistant via USB?

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, usb

I was able to put Windows 8 setup files on my usb from the installer. Now I just upgraded my machine to Mountain Lion. I have gone through the BC Assistant and it only asks for my Windows CD to be put into my drive. There is no longer an option to install via other media.

Anyone know of a workaround to install with USB stick?

Comment: Does your system meet the requirements under

"Can I use a downloaded (ISO) version of Windows with Boot Camp?"

here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5639 ?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly answer your question but may help solve your problem: create a bootable Windows DVD from the Windows 8 setup files, as explained  [here](http://www.windowsvalley.com/create-bootable-windows-8-iso-dvd/).

I did it myself some months ago when upgrading Windows XP to Windows 8, and it worked without a hitch.

You will need:

- Access to a Windows computer.
- `oscdimg.exe`, a command-line tool for creating bootable Windows ISO files. This file is part of a larger download:

  - For Windows XP SP2 with KB926044/2003 SP1 with KB926044/2003 SP2 you'll need the *Automated Installation Kit* at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10333
  - For Windows 8/7/2012/2008 R2/Vista/2008 you'll need the *Assessment and Deployment Kit* at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30652
- Windows 8 setup files.

The steps are:

1. Download and install `oscdimg.exe`.
2. Put the Windows 8 setup files in a folder. While any name will do I found `C:\WIN8AIO` to be a popular choice, so I'll use it.
3. Open a command prompt as administrator and create the ISO image `C:\WIN8DVD.ISO` like this:

   ```
   \path\to\oscdimg.exe -lWIN8DVD -t10/26/2012:00:00 -m -u2 -bC:\WIN8AIO\boot\etfsboot.com C:\WIN8AIO C:\WIN8DVD.ISO
   ```

   For more information on `oscdimg.exe` and its command line options see [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749036%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) at Microsoft.
4. Burn `C:\WIN8DVD.ISO` and use it with Boot Camp Assistant on your Mac.

Comment: The question is about installation from USB, not from a DVD.

Answer (score 0):

This article entitled ["How To Easily Install Windows 7 & 8 onto An External USB Storage with PWBoot"](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-easily-install-windows-7-8-onto-an-external-usb-storage-with-pwboot/) published on the 27th May 2013 by *K.Chen* for *nextofwindows.com* maybe helpful and provides step by step instructions (which should be followed very carefully).

[PWBoot](http://reboot.pro/topic/6851-project-pwboot-latest-version-302/) (Portable Windows Boot) aims to simplify the process of making Windows Operating System to boot from any USB storage devices.

Comment: The question was about creating the USB installer, not installing to a USB disk. However, have you verified that this works to boot Windows from a Mac? In my experience this procedure works to create the USB installation but it won't boot on a Mac.