# Install Windows with Bootcamp from a file?

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I have an iso containing Windows 7 that was given to me by a friend. He said I could just put it on a flash drive and install Windows 7 with Bootcamp, but I don't know how to do that the right way.

How do I load the iso onto the flash drive and use that for Bootcamp?

Comment: Let's pick this apart. We strongly discourage two part questions since someone that knows a great answer to one part may not answer as they don't know the second. We don't restrict asking three questions. I'd edit out part B of this and then ask it as a second question. Once you have two good answers to each piece, you are of course free to ask how to combine the specific answers you choose as a third question.

Comment: I am slightly confused here. In what way did I ask three questions? The "Can anyone help me out here?" was meant as a polite way of ending the paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It's much better now from my standpoint. :-) Are you using [Bootcamp 5](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/) and a Mac that supports Win 7? Assuming yes to both, if no one has a quick answer, you might edit in what step fails you and what error or condition prevents you from following the manual linked above to get Windows installed in Bootcamp.

Comment: It is showing 5.0.3 and my Mac is only a year old, so I am pretty sure it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Valid ISO images are explicitly supported by Apple in the latest Bootcamp software, so you should be good to go by following this guide and setting up Bootcamp to install Windows 7 in a separate partition on your main mac volume.

- [http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5634 - Boot Camp: System requirements for Microsoft Windows operating systems](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5634)

Answer (score 1):

This article entitled ["How To Easily Install Windows 7 & 8 onto An External USB Storage with PWBoot"](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-easily-install-windows-7-8-onto-an-external-usb-storage-with-pwboot/) published on the **27th May 2013** by ***K.Chen*** for *nextofwindows.com* maybe helpful and provides step by step instructions (which should be followed very carefully).

[PWBoot](http://reboot.pro/topic/6851-project-pwboot-latest-version-302/) (Portable Windows Boot) aims to simplify the process of making Windows Operating System to boot from any USB storage devices.

Comment: Interesting - is this question any different than this other one at this point? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92013/how-to-install-windows-8-with-bootcamp-5-assistant-via-usb

Comment: By far, as Windows 8 has had numerous issues with Bootcamp so far.

Comment: @Justin Perfect. We can leave this open as a windows 7 only question and the others as a more general query